# Mouse listener flood-protection only reports first clicks

Tags: java, events, mouse

```
public void get_Mouse_press()
{
    boolean leftDown = Mouse.isButtonDown(0);
    boolean rightDown = Mouse.isButtonDown(1);
    validate_Mouse_press(leftDown, rightDown);

}

public void validate_Mouse_press(boolean left, boolean right)
{
    if (left == true)
    {
        if(repeatLeftPressed == false)
        {
            System.out.println("Left mouse button down");
            repeatLeftPressed = true;   
            repeatLeftReleased = false;
        }
        if(repeatLeftPressed == true)
        {   
            repeatLeftReleased = false;
        }
    }
    if (right == true)
    {
        if(repeatRightPressed == false)
        {
            System.out.println("Right mouse button down");
            repeatRightPressed = true;
            repeatRightReleased = false;
        }
        if(repeatRightPressed == true)
        {   
            repeatRightReleased = false;
        }
    }
    if (left == false)
    {
        if(repeatLeftReleased = false)
        {
            System.out.println("Left mouse button released");
            repeatLeftReleased = true;
            repeatLeftPressed = false;
        }
        if(repeatLeftReleased == true)
        {   
            repeatLeftPressed = false;
        }
    }
    if (right == false)
    {
        if(repeatRightReleased = false)
        {
            System.out.println("Right mouse button released");
            repeatRightReleased = true;
            repeatRightPressed = false;
        }
        if(repeatRightReleased == true)
        {   
            repeatRightPressed = false;
        }
    }

}
```

When i run my program, it does not function properly. I expect the program to print to the screen the appropriate statement, one time , each time a mouse key is pressed, and each time a mouse key is released. This is to prevent flooding from the rapid fps.
However, it only display when I click the left or right key the first time.

The output is

```
"Left mouse button down"
"Right mouse button down"
```

The above output is all that displays, despite many clicks. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I don't know how else to go about preventing the console flooding you get when polling the mouse button states, without some sort of console printing control. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Or is this sufficient, with just a few overlooked errors?

Comment: I have reviewed it. Multiple times, Where is the error?

Comment: Ah, assignment statements in comparison statements. Wrong operators. I just caught that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `repeatLeftReleased = false` as it an assignment (that evaluates to `false`) and is *not* an equality. Similarly the code for the right-release has this flaw. The logic is fine (at least until I use Auto Clicker to win all the levels ;-), although there is duplication and NOP code.

To prevent this issue in the future, don't use `== true/== false` but rather simply use the boolean variable/expression value directly;

```
if (!left)
{
    if(!repeatLeftReleased) // no chance for `=` now!
    {
        System.out.println("Left mouse button released");
        repeatLeftReleased = true;
        repeatLeftPressed = false;
    }
    if(repeatLeftReleased) // this is always true here
    {   
        repeatLeftPressed = false;
    }
}
```